# Override Onsen ui dialog animation direction

Tags: onsen-ui

Is it possible to override the transition direction of the dialog show/hide? currently, it's moving to the bottom to top, can I change it to the top to bottom or right to left etc. As per the [documentation](https://onsen.io/v1/reference/ons-dialog.html), they are supporting only 'default' or 'none', so I am looking for the custom code using css or js. using onsen ui v1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently the only animation options are "slide" and "fade" that you give to the show method of the dialog object. `dialog.show({animation: "slide"});` gives a top to bottom fast movement, while `dialog.show({animation: "fade"});` gives a bottom to top movement on the iOS and a fade animation on Android.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, myself accomplished my requirement by using custom element and CSS3 properties like transition and translate.